# Azure DevOps Az Task still loads RM modules and fails to load Az modules

Tags: azure-devops

We are trying to extract Azure Advisor recommendations using PowerShell.
Unfortunately, Advisor doesnt seem to have an RM module.

Hence relying on DevOps Azure Task version 4.* which supposedly is for Az modules.

However, it appears that RM modules still gets loaded into the session per error below:

```
##[warning]Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide
```

Hence I am resorting to using Uninstall-AzureRM command.

```
##[error]Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'.
```

This is more or less what I am trying.

```
uninstall-azurerm
install-Module Az -force -scope currentuser
install-Module Az.Advisor -force -scope currentuser
import-module Az.Advisor
Get-AzAdvisor recommendations
```

Any help is appreciated either using RM or Az modules.

Comment: Did you try to run only `Get-AzAdvisor` without uninstall and install?

Comment: Yes. that throws module not available error.
    ##[error]The term 'Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.